# Multiple text boxes to call the same VBA procedure

Tags: vba, ms-access, textbox

I am developing an Access Database and have several forms; all of which have the same text box on them.
The text box for each form is from the same record source, same name, same properties, etc. After the textbox is updated I have VBA running an Instr procedure which captures key phrases commonly used in these text boxes and replaces them with a common phrase.
How can I get each text box from each form to call the same procedure, that way if I have to improve the code over time I am only doing so in one place versus going to each form to update the code.

Example code.

```
textbox1_AfterUpdate()

Dim A as TextBox
Set A= Me.Textbox1

If InStr(A," Attachment Number ") Then
  Me.FunctionalArea.SetFocus
  A=Replace(A,"Attachment Number","<<Att."&" "& Left(Me.FunctionalArea).text,1)&""&"XXX>>")
  A=SetFocus
End If

If InStr(A, " Program Name ") Then
  A = Replace(A, " Program Name ", " <<ProgramNameXX>> ")
End If

If InStr(A, " Office Address ") Then
  A = Replace(A, " Office Address ", " <<OfficeAddressXX>> ")
End If
```

Comment: Well.  That's what Subs and Functions are for.....

Comment: Understand this would end up being a sub in a module. I tried creating a module and calling it AutoTag(). I placed the code in that sub, and then in the textbox1 after update I put call AutoTag, but it didn't work.

Comment: I just tried it again. Had to take out all the "Me." first. Once I did that, I am now getting an object required error. Based on my knowledge in excel, I assume that the code just cant find the textbox. But I am unsure how to declare the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just call the code with a parameter of the textbox.

Something along the lines of

```
Public Sub textbox1_AfterUpdate()

    DoTextBoxActions Me.Textbox1
    
End Sub


Public Sub DoTextBoxActions(ByRef ipTextBox As TextBox)

        If InStr(ipTextBox.Text, " Attachment Number ") Then
          ipTextBox.FunctionalArea.SetFocus
          ipTextbox=Replace(ipTextbox.Text,"Attachment Number","<<Att."&" "& Left(ipTextbox.FunctionalArea).text,1)&""&"XXX>>")
          ipTextBox.Parent.SetFocus = SetFocus
        End If
        
        If InStr(ipTextBox.Text, " Program Name ") Then
          ipTextBox = Replace(ipTextBox.Text, " Program Name ", " <<ProgramNameXX>> ")
        End If
        
        
        If InStr(ipTextBox.Text, " Office Address ") Then
          ipTextBox = Replace(ipTextBox, " Office Address ", " <<OfficeAddressXX>> ")
        End If
           
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! Your code is a 99% solution. The only thing I am having trouble with is when the code calls to set focus to the functional area text box. I get an error saying method or data member not found. Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry.  I'm not a user of excel.  Just trying to point you in a workable direction.  Have you tried looking at the object browser.  Maybe change 'ipTextBox.Parent.SetFocus = SetFocus' to just ipTextBox.SetFocus'.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Just to clarify I'm not using excel. I am using access. My vba knowledge is very basic and I learned it in excel. Additionally I'm not having trouble with the parent.setfocus. Im having trouble with the iptextbox.fuctionarea.setfocus. I'm trying to get the code to look at the textbox called "functional area"and take the first letter of the word in that textbox. Other than this one hiccup your code words great.

Comment: IN that case you need to use a property or method that allows you to get to the object /form that holds the textbox called 'Functional area'.  With the limited data you have provided its difficult to be more specific.  Typically I'd be looking generically at something like  'ipTextBox.Controls.Item("Functional Area").SetFocus' or 'ipTextBox.Parent.Controls.Item("Functional Area").SetFocus'.

Comment: I see. Okay. I'm going to try out these suggestions as soon as I can get back on my computer. I'll post an update tonight or tomorrow.

Comment: I haven't had a chance to try your other suggestions yet. Other work obligations took over. However at the core of your advice your code works so I appreciate your input. I'm marking this as solved since I will be able to use it eventually. Just gotta figure out the last little bit. Thanks again!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this.

When you place that text box on each form, in place of building a "event" code stub, you can enter this:

=MyFunctionName()

Or, thus in your case, you would place this code in a standard code module (NOT the forms code module).

```
Public Function MyGlobalAfterUpdate

   ' pick up the form and the control
   ' do this first, do this fast, do this right away
   ' since a timer event, mouse click, focus change etc. can
   ' case the screen.ActiveForm, and screen.ActiveControl to change
   ' once we grab these values, then you ok
   
   Debug.Print "global after"

   Dim MyControl    As TextBox
   Dim MyForm       As Form

   Set MyForm = Screen.ActiveForm
   Set MyControl = Screen.ActiveControl


   Debug.Print "Control name = " & MyControl.Name
   Debug.Print "Text of control = " & MyControl.Value

   Dim strText As String

   strText = MyControl.Value

   Debug.Print strText

   ' note that we have FULL use of the form values
   ' in place of me!Some value, or control?
   ' you can go
   MyForm.Refresh
   MyForm!LastUpdate = now()
   
   ' save the data in the form
   ' If MyForm.Dirty = true then MyForm.Dirty = False

End sub
```

So you are free to do whatever you want in this code. And you simple replace "me" the forms reference with MyForm, but once you grabbed the active form, then anything you would or could do with "Me", you can do the SAME with MyForm. As noted, you could in theory using Screen.ActiveForm, but you are MUCH better to pick up a reference as fast as possible and as soon as possible, since those values and focus could change, and often it will - so get/grab/take a reference to the controls as fast and as soon as possible. Once you grabbed the reference from screen, then minor changes in focus etc. don't matter - since you picked up the form and control right away.

The key concept, the key takeaway? you can grab both the current form with screen.ActiveForm, and you can get/grab the current control that fired the after update event with Screen.ActiveControl.

So, in summary:

Don't create a code stub in the form. In the controls after update event, place the name of the PUBLIC function in a STANDARD code module.

eg like this:

```
=MyGlobalAfterUpdate()
```